# text won't show on small screens

Tags: html, css

the text appears fine on desktop but when i use chrome inspect and resize to mobile view the text does not appear any more....i used other tags for text but still the same problem.

```css
.product-full {
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        margin: 38px 0 0 0;
    }

    .product-full a {
        margin: 0 13px 0 13px;
        width: auto;
        height: 220px;
    }

    .product-full p {
        margin: 0;
    }

    img[alt~="from"] {
        position: absolute;
        max-width: 59.78px;
        max-height: 32px;
        margin-left: 10.67px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    img[alt~="product"] {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 50%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

```html
<body>

<div class="product-full">
    <a>
       <img src="/Assets/from-amazon.png" alt="from">
        <img src="/Assets/product.png" alt="product">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </a>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: What is tag <a> ?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to check if you have a meta tag in your `<head>` tag or not. Because meta tags are important for different viewports. I have added important meta tags for responsive design.

If you have meta tags then you should add media queries in CSS for different screen sizes. I have added a media query for mobile view.
Hope it helps.

```css
.product-full {
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        margin: 38px 0 0 0;
    }

    .product-full a {
        margin: 0 13px 0 13px;
        width: auto;
        height: 220px;
    }

    .product-full p {
        margin: 0;
    }

    img[alt~="from"] {
        position: absolute;
        max-width: 59.78px;
        max-height: 32px;
        margin-left: 10.67px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    img[alt~="product"] {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 50%;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    @media (max-width:767px){
         .product-full p{font-size:20px;}
      
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>



<body>


<div class="product-full">
    <a>
       <img src="/Assets/from-amazon.png" alt="from">
        <img src="/Assets/product.png" alt="product">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i do have the meta tag and the media queries... still no luck